# Microsoft ESB Toolkit 2.0 for WCF Services

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, esb-toolkit-2.0

Can we have ESB Toolkit 2.0 to route the incoming messages to WCF services hosted in IIS?
I'm thinking of using content based routing, validation and transformation capabilities of ESB for WCF services.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you can.

The routing mechanism from BizTalk ESB Toolkit 2.0 supports WCF services.
All WCF bindings are supported, including custom bindings as made available from the various WCF adapters.

All properties on the request-response EndPoint may be specified.

But the WCF service consumed from ESB Toolkit does not necessarily have to be hosted in IIS. As long as a corresponding binding exists for the service, you will be able to use it.

May I suggest that you question only calls for a yes or no answer. Do you have some difficulties using the Itinerary Designer?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely use ESB toolkit for route your messages to WCF service.
Both Static and BRE resolvers can be used and wold require you to pass the following parameters.

[image]

I am also using a map to create the WCF Service Request so I am using a Transform as well (as shown in the image) but you can use it without that as well.